# When to split a (MySQL) table

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

I have a `user` table for my website and I am currently in the process of redesigning the entire thing.

The information I will store will consist of about 30 fields. Not all fields are required for all users. For example, users can have address information (street, city etc.) and bussiness information (company name, number, etc.).

I'm wondering if it would be best in this case to have a large table with 30 fields (where some fields can be null), or to split up the table into multiple tables linked by user IDs with foreign keys. What would be the pros and cons in terms of

- Best practice (clear and organized code/database)
- Speed
- Storage space

I know there are similar questions about this topic but I couldn't find any that matches my case. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Here is a tut of how to [DB normalization](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)

Comment: 30 columns is not a large table. null storage takes little to no space on most databases. To properly answer your question we need to know the logical model: do you need to distinguish between different types of users, this sort of thing.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Basically all users can use the basic functionality. Then there is a `user_type` column which indicates whether the user is normal/admin/etc. and gives them access to parts of the website. Other functionality is based on the amount of information stored. For example, users with address information can buy products.

Comment: To give a complete answer one will have to see the full picture. as of now, I don't really see a good reason to break this table to multiple tables.

Comment: Storage and speed will not vary much.